# How to loop within mysql

Tags: mysql

How do I do the following?

Go through a file and pick all unique "patient_ID" that have a specific "diagnosis" and then go back to get all diagnosis of those unique patients? But as a single query.

I have the first part

```
SELECT DISTINCT patient_ID, diagnosis WHERE diagnosis = "123";
```

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly, you can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.patient_id = t.patient_id and t1.diagnosis = 123)
```

This brings all the rows of patients that have at least one `123` diagnosis.

Answer (score 0):

This subquery:

```
SELECT patient_ID FROM tablename WHERE diagnosis = '123'
```

returns all the `patient_ID`s with `diagnosis = 123'`.
So you can use it with the operator `IN`:

```
SELECT patient_ID, diagnosis 
FROM tablename
WHERE patient_ID IN (SELECT patient_ID FROM tablename WHERE diagnosis = '123')
```